# Securing the alfresco global properties file

Tags: alfresco-share, alfresco-ldap

For active directory configuration I need to give our IT admin password

```
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=
```

He feels that its a big security concern as other developers working on alfresco has the access to the global property file.

Is there any possibility to encrypt the global property file ?

Alfresco version 4.2e

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such functionality in the Community Editon.
Alfresco introduced property encryption in a later enterprise version but in the CE there is no such thing even in the latest version.

Maybe you also read the Alfresco forums thread [alfresco-global.properties file encrypting](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/alfresco-global-properties-file-encrypting/td-p/128386)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to encrypt the alfresco-global.properties, you should be adding a **new user** to your AD for alfresco instance(s) let's say alfresco:$3creT and **grant** ***read permission*** on your AD *users* and *groups* for that user !